# Audio player with lyrics loaded from file

Tags: sound, files, podcast, lyrics

I'm looking for an audio player (may be for gnome, kde, xfce, doesn't matter) in which I'd be able to load my own lyrics from a file. I have some language-learning podcasts and would like to have a transcript for them to automatically appear when the track changes. 
I've been searching quite thoroughly and couldn't find any player that would load lyrics from a file, all of them search the web to find the lyrics (I've even tried the heavy amarok) and it obviously won't work for a podcast. 
Thank you for you help!

EDIT:
Ok, I've found a great player! Actually Enigmapond recommended it to me on ubuntuforums:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1980046 
It's named Guayadeque and you can read about it's advantages I've immediately noticed in the thread I've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Guayadeque](https://www.guayadeque.org/)

With Guayadeque you can edit lyrics and save them after you have finished.

[image]

Comment: Official website: http://www.guayadeque.org/ ; GitHub repository: https://github.com/anonbeat/guayadeque

Comment: @DenilsonSáMaia thanks for the notice

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend GNOME Mplayer for you. I'm using it and I've never had any problems with subtitles.

Answer (score 0):

See also [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/984990/8822) which recommends [gmusicbrowser](http://gmusicbrowser.org)

Answer (score 0):

[Fauxdacious](https://wildstar84.wordpress.com/fauxdacious/) (which itself is a fork of [Audacious](https://audacious-media-player.org/)) adds support for loading Lyrics from the web, from local files, or from the audio file metadata.

> When playing a song, ie. "myfavoritesong.mp3", Fauxdacious will first search for a lyric file ("myfavoritesong.lrc") in the same directory the song is in (for local song files), then for lyrics embedded in an ID3 tag, then for "Song Title.lrc" in ~/.config/fauxdacious[-instancename]/lyrics// (the global lyrics cache). Failing that, Fauxdacious will seek to pull lyrics from the internet using the Perl FauxdaciousLyricsHelper program. If lyrics are fetched from the web, you will have an option to [Save locally].

→ [FAQ, question 22](https://wildstar84.github.io/fauxdacious/FAQ.htm#22)